# Should I use TINYINT for ID (PK) field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, schema

Should I perform this type of optimisation if I know that a table can't have more records than 10?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You should also say `UNSIGNED`:  `TINYINT UNSIGNED`.  Range 0..255; 1 byte.

Actually, it is such a tiny optimization that I don't bother mentioning it.

Think about using the smallest datatypes when you first `CREATE` the table; it is messier to make the change later.

`SMALLINT UNSIGNED`:  0..65535, 2 bytes
`MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`:  0..16M, 3 bytes
`INT UNSIGNED`:  0..4B, 4 bytes

Keep in mind that certain operations "burn" `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids.  This could lead to an unexpected overflow.  Examples:  `INSERT IGNORE` and `REPLACE`.  They *may* preallocate an id *before* realizing that it won't be needed.